# How to get real exception message when using UpdatePanel?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, webforms, error-handling

I'm not seeing the real error in my custom error page when using an UpdatePanel. In my Global.asax I have the following code:

```
Sub Application_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    'Get the exception
    Dim lastError = Server.GetLastError()
    If lastError IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim ex As Exception = lastError.GetBaseException()
        If ex IsNot Nothing Then
            'Log the error
            If Log.IsErrorEnabled Then
                log4net.ThreadContext.Properties("method") = ex.TargetSite.Name
                log4net.ThreadContext.Properties("userId") = User.Current.UserName
                Log.Error(ex.Message, ex)
            End If
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

If I review the log or set a breakpoint I can see that I'm getting a timeout issue. Then I have the following code to send the user to the error page and display the error:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        if (args.get_error() != undefined) {
            // Let the framework know that the error is handled,
            //  so it doesn't throw the JavaScript alert.
            args.set_errorHandled(true);

            var errorMessage = args.get_error().message.replace(/</gi, "&lt;").replace(/>/gi, "&gt;");

            // If there is, show the custom error.
            window.location = _root + 'ShowError.aspx?error=' + encodeURI(errorMessage)
        }
    }
</script>
```

But the error I'm getting from args.get_error() is this instead:

> Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException:
>   An unknown error occurred while
>   processing the request on the server.
>   The status code returned from the
>   server was: 500

What do I have to do to get the timeout error to the error page?

Comment: Also, I have customErrors mode="On" and if I add defaultRedirect="ShowError.aspx" the status code changes from 500 to 0, but I still get the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398934.aspx

Although their example wouldn't compile and didn't give me exactly what I needed it got me in the right direction. I was able to control the message that gets put in the Async exception using this code:

```
Protected Sub ScriptManager1_AsyncPostBackError(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.AsyncPostBackErrorEventArgs)
    If e.Exception.Data("ExtraInfo") IsNot Nothing Then
        ScriptManager1.AsyncPostBackErrorMessage = _
           e.Exception.Message & _
           e.Exception.Data("ExtraInfo").ToString()
    Else
        ScriptManager1.AsyncPostBackErrorMessage = e.Exception.Message
    End If
End Sub
```

I also had to remove the defaultRedirect in the web.config and only conditionally redirect if it was not an async call. I did that by changing my Global.asax to this:

```
Sub Application_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    'Get the exception
    Dim lastError = Server.GetLastError()
    If lastError IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim ex As Exception = lastError.GetBaseException()
        If ex IsNot Nothing Then
            'Log the error
            If Log.IsErrorEnabled Then
                log4net.ThreadContext.Properties("method") = ex.TargetSite.Name
                log4net.ThreadContext.Properties("userId") = User.Current.DomainName
                Log.Error(ex.Message, ex)
            End If
            If Not IsAsyncPostBackRequest(Request) Then
                Server.Transfer("~/ShowError.aspx")
            End If
        End If
    End If

End Sub

Public Function IsAsyncPostBackRequest(request As HttpRequest) As Boolean
    Dim values = request.Headers.GetValues("X-MicrosoftAjax")
    If values IsNot Nothing Then
        For Each value In values
            Dim parts = value.Split(","c)
            For Each part In parts
                If part.Trim() = "Delta=true" Then
                    Return True
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End If
    Return False
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into some similar stuff.  You're mostly correct, but you can still use your custom errors attribute in the web.config, by just indicating on your script manager to ignore it with this attribute:  AllowCustomErrorsRedirect="false"